# Usage of pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

I am still new to multithreading programming, I don't quite understand why `pthread_cleanup_push` and `pthread_cleanup_pop` are only used when a thread is getting called, whereas calling `pthread_exit()` does not require cleanup. Why?

Comment: Is your intent to learn C or C++? You tagged both, but they are two completely different languages. If your intent is to learn C++ you don't need to worry about any of this, and you should use `std::thread` instead.

Comment: sorry I changed the tag, this is a c topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of **thread cancellation clean-up handlers**, which is what `pthread_cleanup_push`/`pthread_cleanup_pop` manage, is to perform cleanup of user defined data and structures used by the thread **when it is cancelled**. Since cancellation is usually an abnormal termination method, you can register handlers to "clean things up" when a thread is cancelled, because the thread will not be able to do so itself before being terminated.

For example, say you have a mutex lock shared between two threds A and B. Thread A acquires the lock, and then gets canceled before having a chance to release it. Thread B then tries to acquire the lock, but gets stuck indefinitely because the lock was never (and never will) be released by A. To avoid this, using a thread cancellation clean-up handler, you can make sure that when A is cancelled, the mutex lock is released.

Under normal circumstances such as `return` from a thread or `pthread_exit()`, it is assumed that such a clean-up process is not needed, as it's the thread itself that decides when to exit, and has full control of what to do before exiting, so any clean-up can be performed easily.

**NOTE** though that calls to `pthread_exit()` will still cause the cleanup handlers to run. This is because `pthread_exit()` could be called by other functions used by the thread that you may or may not have control over (I would say it's an uncommon case, but still).

Comment: That clarifies my question. Thank you.

Comment: I think it should be noted that for `pthread_exit()` (but not `return` from thread start) the thread's cleanup handlers will be called (which makes sense because the call to `pthread_exit()` might be performed by a called function).